# Node.js application running on AWS EC2 throws "Assertion failed: new_time >= loop->time, file src\win\timer.c, line 37" error

Tags: node.js, windows, amazon-web-services, timer

I've Node.js application running on AWS EC2 Windows server but it throws the following error intermitently

> Assertion failed: new_time >= loop->time, file src\win\timer.c, line
>   37

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Suggest you try it on a new Windows EC2 instance. Related: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8234 and https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/1633.

Comment: Did you ever resolve your issue? I have this problem now

Comment: Restart your AWS workspace can help.